# SmartGit and Git How to compare with remote?

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm quite new with git (and all version control software). I've installed SmartGit 3 as my graphical interface. I've create a bare repo and cloned it. What i'd like to know, is how am I supposed to pull from the server (without overwriting), compare the modifications (changes) between my current local version and the one from the remote server, and select the changes I want to keep (like in meld or kdiff3).

As we speak, when I pull from the server, it completely overwrite my local version, and when I push, it overwrite the remote server's version with the local one (last commit).

I want to be able to compare the differences between my local version and the remote version when I pull and/or push.

I tried to figured out how to do it, but just can't find it. I've seen a friend of mine doing something similar with git gui (I think he was merging something, but I am not sure).

Anyway, I'm sure there's something I understand wrong, but if someone could help me with the procedure of how to do it (using SmartGit 3), would be really helpful.

Comment: git pull is basically:  git getch followed by git merge.   just do a fetch by itself, then you can diff and compare and merge what you want

Comment: @Jeff Shelman thanks for the answer, but how am I supposed to do it in SmartGit 3, the only button I have is pull, which I can select "just fetch changes" but it does nothing?

Comment: I don't have a SmartGit3 install to play with.  It would seem that you can uncheck the merge remote changes checkbox http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation.html?page=commands then perform the merge manually.

Comment: Installed SmartGit 3 and played with it a bit, this doesn't seem as intuitive as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

In your SmartGit3 project,  right-click repository settings (alt-enter) and uncheck the "commit merged remote changes".

Now when you do a "pull",  if you just fetch the changes,  they will be fetched into origin/master branch.

You can merge from there in the merge window (select all branches from the dropdown or just "master and origin/master") and the commits on the remote (origin/master) branch should show up in the list.

Looks like once you fetch (above) you can see the changes vs your local HEAD from the log window.  select all branches (or "master and origin/master") on the little drop down next to the Filter box/Default coloring dropdown.  You can then cherry pick merge the commits into your local master.

Comment: You can also select the commit where master is on and the commit where origin/master is on at the same time. This will give you the overall difference between those two commits in the Files area.

Comment: @mstrap well, that was reaaally helpful, exactly what I needed to review release changes before fishing them.